# WCF Service Reference The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: asp.net, wcf, certificate

In my Visual Studio 2015 web application project (C#), I try to add a WCF service reference, https://eldws.fmcsa.dot.gov, and get the error as follows:

`There was an error downloading 'https://eldws.fmcsa.dot.gov/$metadata'. The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://eldws.fmcsa.dot.gov/'. The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

If I enter this URL directly into browser, I first get the warning message that

[Prompt error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzyiv.png)

When I click the listed credential, the browser shows the WSDL contents successfully.
My project setting is that Anonymous Authentication is Enabled. SSL Enabled is true, and Windows Authentication is Disabled. Changing the Anonymous Authentication to Disabled and Windows Authentication to Enabled does not solve the problem. I also verified that I have IIS Express Development Certificate installed in Personal Certificate.

It seems that Adding the service reference within Visual Studio is rejected by the server due to not having some kind of certificate. How do I configure VS to have required certificate or authentication as server requires when adding WCF service reference?

Changing the project configuration in VS to enable/disable anonymous authentication/windows authentication does not help. I do not have any knowledges about the setup of the server. I do have public key from the server, but as far as I know, that is only used when exchanging info with the server, not being used when just referencing the service. Since I am adding a new service reference, there is nothing to be configured in web.config yet.

Answer (score 0):

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
> 'Anonymous'. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

This error usually indicates that the WCF server authenticates the client with a certificate. You can add this in server like below:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

The part of authenticating the client with a certificate, you could refer to the below link for details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication

Comment: Thank you Jiayao for your help. However, I cannot do anything on server side. I am just on client side, trying to add service reference in my web application, and get the error. It seems that I must have some kind of certificate in order to access the URL. I just don't know what certificate I need, and how VS gets this certificate (from where?) during the adding service reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use X.509 certificate in client-side. Client certificates are typically stored in a personal storage area at the current user location. You can see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates) to find how to get it and follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate) to configure.